# How do I search and replace "foo/" with "/bar"

Tags: sed

I want to replace `foo/` with `/bar` in a current directory.

However I cannot use `sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *` because of the backslashes

What do I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can totally still use sed.

You can either escape the slash like this:

```
sed -i 's/foo\//\/bar/g'
```

Or you can use different delimiters with sed (it doesn't have to be a backslash), like this:

```
sed -i 's@foo/@/bar@g'
```

I think either of those should do the trick.

Comment: thanks @mrcheshire. Ive discovered that when sed executes the command it stops when it gets to a folder, when I'd like it to ignore the folders,